# How to allow users the ability to customise their own area - colours or wallpaper

Tags: colors, wallpaper

I need help with some elements for my website, to enable logged in users to be able to alter the colour or background of their logged in area. I am looking for the best way to quickly accomplish this.

I would like something similar to this:

onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!

Though it needs to be permanent and remain after logging back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution I made in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tycyy15L/5/

```
 window.onload = function() {


var boxlength = document.getElementsByClassName("coloredBox").length;


for(i = 0; i < boxlength; i++){
document.getElementsByClassName("coloredBox")[i].onclick = function(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
            }
    }

}
```

(see js fiddle for the rest) and cookie version.

If it needs to be permanent, you'll most likely need to use a database. If it's semi-permanent, you could use cookies like my fiddle does.

Comment: Thank you, this does change the background colour. However when accessing another page the colour reverts as it is only applied to the page it is present on. Can you suggest how I can apply this to multiple pages?

Comment: This section of the code     if(document.cookie != undefined){
   
  document.body.style.backgroundColor =  document.cookie.substr(6);
   
    } should be put on all the pages you wan't the background to persist on.

Comment: Currently, the cookie is not activating in Chrome, if I refresh the page the code is present on it resets, though it remains active in Internet Explorer. However, applying the code to additional pages is not currently working. Do you have a solution for this? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you with this. My fiddle works in the browsers I've tested with. The cookie I set is just an example. I'd research more if I were you. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. The cookie that you set should apply across the pages in your domain. If it doesn't, something is clearing it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Starkey. I really appreciate it!